# Problems While Trying To Compile MacVim

Tags: vim, makefile, compilation, macvim

I'm trying to compile MacVim on my Macbook Pro, but while it's running `make`, I got some errors:

```
=== BUILD NATIVE TARGET MacVim OF PROJECT MacVim WITH THE DEFAULT CONFIGURATION (Release) ===
Check dependencies
PBXCp build/Release/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim ../Vim
    cd /Users/Nathan/Downloads/b4winckler-macvim-6e6fac5/src/MacVim
    /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/pbxcp -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -strip-debug-symbols -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/Nathan/Downloads/b4winckler-macvim-6e6fac5/src/MacVim/../Vim /Users/Nathan/Downloads/b4winckler-macvim-6e6fac5/src/MacVim/build/Release/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS

PhaseScriptExecution "Make Document Icons" build/MacVim.build/Release/MacVim.build/Script-1D1C31F00EFFBFD6003FE9A5.sh
    cd /Users/Nathan/Downloads/b4winckler-macvim-6e6fac5/src/MacVim
    /bin/sh -c /Users/Nathan/Downloads/b4winckler-macvim-6e6fac5/src/MacVim/build/MacVim.build/Release/MacVim.build/Script-1D1C31F00EFFBFD6003FE9A5.sh

unzip -jo EnvyCodeR.zip
Archive:  EnvyCodeR.zip
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2
Touch build/Release/MacVim.app
    cd /Users/Nathan/Downloads/b4winckler-macvim-6e6fac5/src/MacVim
    /usr/bin/touch -c /Users/Nathan/Downloads/b4winckler-macvim-6e6fac5/src/MacVim/build/Release/MacVim.app

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
MacVim:
    PhaseScriptExecution "Make Document Icons" /Users/Nathan/Downloads/b4winckler-macvim-6e6fac5/src/MacVim/build/MacVim.build/Release/MacVim.build/Script-1D1C31F00EFFBFD6003FE9A5.sh
(1 failure)

make[1]: *** [macvim] Error 1
make: *** [first] Error 2
```

What I need to do to correct this?

Comment: Do you have an `unzip` command?  Is your file system full?

Comment: Yup, I have `unzip` installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [homebrew formula for MacVim](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/macvim.rb). It states that "Building custom icons fails for many users, so off by default" and goes on to do the following:

```
unless ARGV.include? "--custom-icons"
  inreplace "src/MacVim/icons/Makefile", "$(MAKE) -C makeicns", ""
  inreplace "src/MacVim/icons/make_icons.py", "dont_create = False", "dont_create = True"
end
```

So, I'd suggest making those same modifications to your `src/MacVim/icons/Makefile` and `src/MacVim/icons/make_icons.py`.

Alternatively, use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to build / install MacVim, which is what I've done.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same symptoms.  In addition to the step suggested above, I had to update my copy of brew from 0.7 to 0.8. Here're my steps:

```
cd ~/Developer # where I have my Homebrew installed; ymmv
brew update
brew remove macvim   # My 'damaged' copy
git checkout Library/Formula/macvim.rb   # Make sure it has the above fix
brew install macvim
```

...and this time it installed correctly.

My environment:  Snow Leopard 10.6.8

HTH

Scott